# Read excel file and write it into a SPF file using OleDb in VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledb

I am trying to read an excel file with strict format and then write the content into a SPF file.
Here is my code:

```
Imports System.IO.Path
Imports System.Data


Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fileName As String
        Dim folderName As String
        fileName = ""
        folderName = ""
        Call getFileAndFolderName(fileName, folderName)

    End Sub



 Private Sub getFileAndFolderName(ByRef fileName As String, ByRef folderName As String)
        OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files（*.xls;*.xlsx)|*xls;*xlsx"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        fileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        Try
            folderName = GetDirectoryName(fileName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

        If folderName = "" Or fileName = "" Then
            MsgBox("No File or folder is selected")
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim fileName As String
        Dim folderName As String
        fileName = ""
        folderName = ""
        Call getFileAndFolderName(fileName, folderName)

        Try
            Dim MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim DtSet As DataSet
            Dim DtTable As DataTable
            Dim MyCommand As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            MyConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & fileName & "; " & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
            MyCommand = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
            DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
            DtTable = DtSet.Tables(0)
            Dim S() As Object
            s = DtTable.Rows(0).ItemArray
            MsgBox(s(3).ToString)
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

It works at the first few steps, all the content is written on the DataGridView1, and then I want to
 retrieve the first row to get each cell of it, I don't know how to continue.
The format of the excel file is
Index property1 property2...
1  xx  xx   
2  xx  xx   
3  xx  xx   
Can anyone help me out? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about stf files. I found several definitions.

Comment: Oh, Iam sorry. It's SPF file. I haven't got there yet. I am working on retriving the caption of each column now.

Comment: What is the actual problem here? If you can successfully read the Excel file into the grid then anything to do with Excel is irrelevant to the problem. Is your issue read the data from the `DataTable`/`DataGridView` or is it writing the data to the output file? They are two separate and very different things. If you're going to ask a question on SO it needs to be SPECIFIC. It can;t be about multiple steps in a multi-step process. If you haven't isolated a specific problem then it's too soon to ask a question.

Comment: Ok so my question is  I just want to write it in a  SPF file, may I use StreamWriter to do it??